# JDBC connection is not working in tomcat even after moving mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar

Tags: mysql, jsp, tomcat, jdbc, centos

I am using Tomcat installed on Cent OS for creating JSP pages, but JDBC is not working.

I also moved `mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar` into `lib` directory. The error in page shows:

```
Type Exception report

message javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:912)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:841)
    org.apache.jsp.androidtest.db_005flogin.reg_jsp._jspService(reg_jsp.java:88)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:126)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    org.apache.jsp.androidtest.db_005flogin.reg_jsp._jspService(reg_jsp.java:74)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Comment: Check for the correct version and try to clean and build it again

Comment: version of what? tomcat or mysql or apache.
Sorry for this silly question, but i am a beginer, with very less knowledge in this area.

Comment: Can you update the versions of Java, Tomcat, MySQL you are using?